# used AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm doing a game .

I want create a image hide 20s ,then it appear 5s .I want use AsyncTask but I don't can do it .

Please help me , thanks

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask would be a very bad way to achieve that. Instead use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with either `postDelayed`, `sendMessageDelayed`, or the like...

Comment: @NguyenNguyen: implement a runnable that set's the visibility and post it using postDelayed et al.